# combining multiple files

Tags: awk

I try to combine several files (10 exactly) that have the same Numbers of columns:

```
index lat lon value
```

The files have different numbers of lines (i.e. some `index lat lon` are missing in files)

I want to obtain one file:

index lat lon value_of_file1 value_of_file2 value_of_file3 value_of_file4 value_of_file5 value_of_file6 value_of_file7 value_of_file8 value_of_file9 value_of_file10

The problem is that the "index lat lon" are not in the same order in my files. Here are my inputs (showing only 2 files) for more clarity:

file 1 (showing only a few lines but there are more in actual file):

indice lat lon value

```
50 80 12 50.25
50 80.5 12.5 80.25 
80 80 12 28.52
80 80.5 12.5 35.89
```

file 2:

indice lat lon value

```
80 80 12 38.52
80 80.5 12.5 38.25
30 28.5 52.5 12.35
30 27.5 55.5 18.52
50 80 12 28.52
```

The desired output (showing only the two first lines):

Indice lat lon value_of_file1 value_of_file2 value_of_file3 value_of_file4 value_of_file5 value_of_fine6 value_of_file7 value_of_file8 value_of_file9 value_of_file10

```
50 80 12 50.25 28.52 35.22 78.89 54.42 65.23 89.56 42.25 12.23 40.15
50 80.5 12.5 80.25 0 12.25 56.55 85.96 41.23 22.12 24.57 18.26 47.89
```

How could I do it with awk ?

Comment: Not clear, could you please provide more details on this?

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [edit] your question to show **exactly** the complete output you need to get from the sample input you provided so we have something we can test a potential solution against.

Comment: It looks to me you want to merge the last column of multiple files when the first three columns match. However, what if ex file7 does not have that particular key, do you want to have a set of empy spaces there, or do you want to ignore it?

Comment: I want to have 0.0 for the "empty space" in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you can do this is by creating an array which is not indexed by numbers but by means of the first 3 columns. The easy way to do this is,

```
awk '{key=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3}
     {a[key] = a[key] OFS $4}
     END { for (key in a) print key a[key] }' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

However, if you want `0.0` at the places where files do not have an entry, then you have to keep track of which files do, and which files don't. One way is the following,

```
awk '(FNR==1){f++}
     {key=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3}
     { for(i=b[key]+1; i<f; ++i) a[key] = a[key] OFS "0.0"; b[key]=f }
     { a[key] = a[key] OFS $4 }
     END { for (key in a) {
              for(i=b[key]+1;i<=f; ++i) a[key] = a[key] OFS "0.0";
              print key a[key]
           }
     }' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

How does this work:

- array `a` keeps track of the value string indexed by `key`
- array `b` keeps track of the last file that has been added to `a`, this array is used to be able to add missing zeros. since by default the value of any `b[key]` is `0`, we fix the keys which are missing in the first files. (assume key `"40 50 60"` only appears for the first time in the fourth file, you need to fix the missing `0.0` values for the first three files)
- the variable `f` keeps track of the file number we start processing. It is incremented every time we read the first record of a file (`FNR==1)`
- Every time we add an entry, we first check what the last file was that was added and fill the missing bits up with "0.0".
- At the end of all things, before we print the values, we first check if we have missing values "0.0" from the final files. If so, we add them to `a[key]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using Perl:

```
perl -nle '
    ($k1, $k2, $k3, $v) = split;
    push @{$seen{"$k1 $k2 $k3"}}, $v;
    END { print "$_ @{$seen{$_}}" for sort keys %seen }
' input_*
```

(Translation to awk is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Algorithm:

We iterate over all input files (specified as command line arguments, `input_*`).

The `-n` option means we loop over all lines of all files. `-l` enables automatic end-of-line processing: Incoming lines have their `\n` stripped; printed lines get a `\n` added at the end.

`-e ...` specifies the code.

We `split` each line into whitespace-separated fields.

We use the first three fields (joined with a single space as separator) as a key into a hash (called `%seen`). The hash maps keys (formed from the first three values) to arrays of values. Each line we process adds another value to the end of its corresponding hash entry (using `push`).

At the end, we iterate over the keys of our `%seen` hash and print the key followed by a space followed by the list of values (also space separated). (We sort the keys to get deterministic output over multiple runs of this code.)

The output will be a list of values (from all input values) corresponding to each (index, lat, lon) tuple. They will be ordered according to the order of the input files specified on the command line (values from the first file appear first, etc). If any of the input files does not specify a value for a particular (index, lat, lon) tuple, the corresponding list will be one element shorter. For example, if only file 3 provides a value for (100, 0, 0), the corresponding output will be `100 0 0 value_from_file_3`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to joined the last value (#4 field) of each file taking the 3 first value as a look up key.

If so, you can use this script:

```
awk '{
  a[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3]=(a[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3]?a[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3] OFS:"") ($4?$4:"0.0")
}
END{ 
  for(i in a) print i,a[i]
}' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

The script fills the array `a` with the all 4th values of each `fileX` given as argument.
Once all files are read, it prints all keys and values.

Comment: Thanks for your help! In case of missing value (#4 field) in one of my files, I would like to have 0.0. How can I add it ?

Comment: @user5276228 please look at the updated answer

Comment: @oliv The question states _some `index lat lon` are missing in files_. This implies that your fix will not work. Imagine that `$1 OFS $2 OFS $3` appears only in file 5, or `$1 OFS $2 OFS $3` appears only in file1 and file10.